# PHP rsa get public key from pem file

Tags: php, pear

How can i get publickey from pem file which is created based on rsa 364.
installed crypt(RSA.php) library still getting below error

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method Crypt_RSA::loadKey() in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\rsa.php**

```
$file = "C:\key_file.pem"; 
$keypair = Crypt_RSA_KeyPair::fromPEMString(file_get_contents($file));
$public_key = $keypair->getPublicKey(); 
$rsa_pub_key = Crypt_RSA_Key::fromString($public_key->toString()); 
$rsa_obj = new Crypt_RSA; 
$verify_status = $rsa_obj->validateSign($text,$recieved_signed_sign, $rsa_pub_key) ? 'valid' : 'invalid';
```

getting error as **Fatal error: Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::getPublicKey() in C:\Program Files\xxxx\rsa.php**

Tried same thing openssl_verify. verify is rturning 0 
Trying to verify sign received with base64_encode with 384 rsa key.

```
**$base64DecodedStr = base64_decode("A1a0o8JzF7q12Sr4gJvYjslhg5XVA2fWy28.JyohJ05uyiZGyBpqazqb");
$status = openssl_verify($msg,$base64DecodedStr,$pub_key);**
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Crypt_RSA documentation](http://pear.php.net/reference/Crypt_RSA-1.0.0/Crypt_RSA/Crypt_RSA.html), the Crypt_RSA class doesn't have a loadKey() method. You pass the public key to the constructor as part of an associative array of parameters:

```
$rsa_obj = new Crypt_RSA(array('public_key' => $publickey));
```

Comment: thanks David, I changed code as below $file = "C:\key_file.pem"; $keypair = Crypt_RSA_KeyPair::fromPEMString(file_get_contents($file)); $public_key = $keypair->getPublicKey(); $rsa_pub_key = Crypt_RSA_Key::fromString($public_key->toString()); $rsa_obj = new Crypt_RSA; $verify_status = $rsa_obj->validateSign($text,$recieved_signed_sign, $rsa_pub_key) ? 'valid' : 'invalid'; getting error as Fatal error: Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::getPublicKey() in C:\Program Files\xxxx\rsa.php

Comment: @mazheruddin, check `file_get_contents($file)` result. Your `Crypt_RSA_KeyPair::fromPEMString` is failing to get keypair from PEMString, which can only be the case if something is wrong with a string you passed

Comment: @Rumm, tried $fp = fopen($file, "r"); $pem_data = fread($fp, filesize($file));  fclose($fp);  passed $pem_data to fromPEMString func. still same error able to echo $pem_data

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation: don't use PEAR's Crypt_RSA but rather phpseclib's Crypt_RSA.

PEAR's Crypt_RSA isn't PKCS#1 compliant, meaning signatures or ciphertexst's generated with it are not going to be interoperable with other languages, it doesn't support passworded private keys, and hasn't been actively maintained for years.

More info on phpseclib:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

this is how to load public key in a php and how to know the number of bits used in its encryption and how to encrypt data. remember to split the data into chunks with maximum size of key bytes size.

```
<?php

// Get the public Key 
$pubKey = file_get_contents("public.key");

//echo $pubKey; echo "<br>";

$res=openssl_get_publickey($pubKey);   //convert pubkey into resource
$array=openssl_pkey_get_details($res); //read the resource details
$chunksize= $array['bits'];            //this is the chunk size 4096


$data = 'plaintext data goes here, please encrypt and decrypt the following data';
openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $pubKey);
?>
```