# PHP rsa gePublicKey from .pem file

Tags: php, rsa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP rsa get public key from pem file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648743/php-rsa-get-public-key-from-pem-file)

**Trying to verify received signature with following code.**

```
$file = "C:\key_file.pem";  
$keypair = Crypt_RSA_KeyPair::fromPEMString(file_get_contents($file)); 
$public_key = $keypair->getPublicKey(); 
$rsa_pub_key = Crypt_RSA_Key::fromString($public_key->toString()); 
$rsa_obj = new Crypt_RSA; 
$verify_status =  $rsa_obj->validateSign($text,$recieved_signed_sign, $rsa_pub_key) ? 'valid' : 'invalid';
```

getting error as
**Fatal error: Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::getPublicKey() in C:\Program Files\xxxx\rsa.php**

Comment: Please don't post duplicates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648743/php-rsa-get-public-key-from-pem-file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just dont have installed the pear package [Crypt_RSA](http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_RSA/docs/latest/li_Crypt_RSA.html)

To do so you have to install php-pear and then install the package using it.

On debian basted systems this is usually just a matter of doing

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear

sudo pear i Crypt_RSA
```

on windows i cant tell you but i am sure you can quickly [find howto guides on google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=windows+install+php+pear#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=windows+install+php+%2Bpear&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=ca05a7bb65e82229).

i also think then functions you use require a rather fresh release, so you may have to upgrade pear and update the plugin using the -f switch

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation: don't use PEAR's Crypt_RSA but rather phpseclib's Crypt_RSA.

PEAR's Crypt_RSA isn't PKCS#1 compliant, meaning signatures or ciphertexst's generated with it are not going to be interoperable with other languages, it doesn't support passworded private keys, and hasn't been actively maintained for years.

More info on phpseclib:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/